# Ask about spring4.3.11 + mybatis 3.2 8 <TypeHandler>

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, typehandler

I have a question. Thank you for your understanding that English is inexperienced.

I have a problem with my web project using mybatis in spring web mvc environment.

The problem is this. In DB modeling, the flag value is given as VARCHAR2. In VO.java, the primitive type is given as a boolean. However, there was an error during the select operation.

So, when I created my SqlSessionFactoryBean, I could improve it by passing typeHandlers to the property.

So when I try to code it

**YesNoBooleanTypeHandler.java**

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.HandlesTypes;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;

@MappedJdbcTypes(value = JdbcType.VARCHAR)
@MappedTypes(Boolean.class)
public class YesNoBooleanTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Boolean parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(i, parameter ? "true" : "false");

    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {

        return rs.getString(columnName) != null && "true".equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {

        return rs.getString(columnIndex) != null && "true".equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {

        return cs.getString(columnIndex) != null && "true".equalsIgnoreCase(cs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

}
```

**The SqlSessionFactoryBean setting.**

```
<beans:bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:edu/kosta/kdc/mapper/*Mapper.xml" />
    <beans:property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="edu.kosta.kdc.model.dto" />
    <beans:property name="typeHandlers" value="edu.kosta.kdc.util.YesNoBooleanTypeHandler"/>
</beans:bean>
```

**ResultMap config**

```
 <result column="MEMBER_ISWITHDRAWAL" property="memberIsWithdrawal" typeHandler="edu.kosta.kdc.util.YesNoBooleanTypeHandler" />
```

I set it up like this.

Then

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler' for property 'typeHandlers [0]': no ​​matching editors or conversion strategy found

I can not run the server with an error ..............
I need your advice.

Comment: What is the database column data type which is holding MEMBER_ISWITHDRAWAL column?

Comment: The data type of MEMBER_ISWITHDRAWAL is varchar2.

Comment: A few more questions: What are the possible values MEMBER_ISWITHDRAWAL is going to hold? What is the database you are using? Enhance your question with the pointers highlighted by me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest in my question and for solving it.
Fortunately, we solved the problem. Fill only good things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you specified `typeHandlers` in the `SqlSessionFactoryBean` incorrectly. The `typeHandlers` is an array of `TypeHandler`s but you have provides a `String` value. The configuration should be like this:

```
<beans:bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:edu/kosta/kdc/mapper/*Mapper.xml" />
    <beans:property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="edu.kosta.kdc.model.dto" />
    <beans:property name="typeHandlers">
            <array>
                <beans:bean class="edu.kosta.kdc.util.YesNoBooleanTypeHandler" />
            </array>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Spring cannot instantiate the bean because it cannot convert the string to `TypeHandler`.

Comment: Thank you Roman Konoval. I solved your problem thanks to you. Thank you so much.